# Drupal homepage content jumping

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

My Drupal homepage is loading with the title (H1), subtitle, CTA and image about 15px too high. It's then jumping down into place.

The effect seems to only occur on the homepage.

Initial load image: http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/initial.png

Post jump image: http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/jumped.png

*Sorry can't post images due to low rep.*

*Sorry maxed out at two links - but you can guess my homepage from the above links!*

Does anyone have an idea what's causing this?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your slideshow which initialization and with that its styling comes quite late. You can watch the problem permanently when you go to your site without JavaScript enabled. So to fix that you will need to add some fix styles which simulate the styles which are applied later by your slideshow. You can test those styles again while JavaScript is disabled. It's a bit hard to tell what the best way would be because the styling which comes form your slideshow may be dynamic and dependent on the content of the slideshow and so it could change with the content. Something like that could work:

```
#views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_slides-block {
height: 325px;
}

#views_slideshow_cycle_div_slides-block_0 {
position: absolute;
}
```

But as said, use that with caution and test it.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatley this ends up with my slideshow pushed way too low. See: http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/content-pushed-down.jpg

I also tried just setting the position as absolute but this meant the lower text ended up on top and then pushed down. Any advice?